# Getting MetaData from an image file

Tags: wpf, image-processing

We have images stored on a DB and they are being used to replace an image within a Word document - that bit works perfectly, except where the replacement image is portrait and it's replacing a landscape one, so I'm trying to get the metadata to determine how the image is orientated using this function

```
Public Function GetImageTags(ImageFile() As Byte) As String()
    Try
        Dim vReturnArray() As String = Nothing
        Using MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ImageFile)
            Dim vDecoder As BitmapDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(MS, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default)
            Dim vFrame As BitmapFrame = vDecoder.Frames(0)
            Dim vMetadata As BitmapMetadata = TryCast(vFrame.Metadata, BitmapMetadata)
            If vMetadata IsNot Nothing And vMetadata.Keywords IsNot Nothing Then
                vReturnArray = vMetadata.Keywords.ToArray()
            End If
        End Using
        Return vReturnArray
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

...but it throws the toys out with...

```
This codec does not support the specified property.
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapMetadata.GetQuery(String query)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapMetadata.get_Keywords()
```

...at BitMapMetadata.Keywords. Any idea how I can overcome this and get the keywords?

Thank you

================ UPDATE ================

It appears that the error, and I also tried...

```
vReturnArray = TryCast(vMetadata.GetQuery("System.Keywords"), String())
```

... is only returned for some images, but all that I tried returned Nothing for the String()

Comment: Some codecs (e.g. PNG) do not support the BitmapMetadata.Keywords property. You should access it in a try block.

Comment: Clemens - also tried PngBitmapDecoder

Comment: lightlike - did try that, but opted for a class in the answer below that was far easier to implement. Thank you for taking the time to post the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a really good EXIF class on [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4956/The-ExifWorks-class) that is easy to implement, either with a string link to the file

```
 Dim vEXIF As New ImageEXIF(ImagePath)
            Dim vOrientation As Integer = vEXIF.Orientation
```

or as BitMap

```
 Dim vOrientation As Integer = 0
                    Using vBitmap As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(New IO.MemoryStream(ImageFile))
                        Dim vEXIF As New ImageEXIF(vBitmap)
                        vOrientation = vEXIF.Orientation
                    End Using
```

It would not be difficult to add another Sub to the class for Byte(), but the above conversion is quite straightforward and the class should work with all image types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) to access the image metadata.

Check for the presence of `ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation` on any of the contained Exif directories.

Something like this (sorry it's C# as I don't know VB.NET):

```cs
var orientation = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(imagePath)
    .OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>()
    .Select(d => d.GetObject(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation))
    .First(o => o != null);
```